# Block access to files and sub directory with .htaccess?

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have nearly 30 php files, 4 sub directories in my directory. I want to block some php files and sub directories from user in direct viewing like  `http://bhavani.com/hai.php`

My currect `htaccess` file

```
## Enable Mod Rewrite, this is only required once in each .htaccess file
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteBase / 
## Test for access to includes directory
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /includes/ .*$ [NC] 
## Test that file requested has php extension 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} ^.+\.php$ 
## Forbid Access 
RewriteRule .* - [F,NS,L]
```

How to do it?

Comment: You could create a simple if() statement at the start of the php file, like user logged in or whatever you require for access to them and if not then header("404"); exit;

Answer (score 5):

You can filter the files like this

```
<Files ~ "\.php$">
  Deny from all
</Files>
```

And directory like this

```
<Directory "/subdirectory">
  Deny from all
</Directory>
```

Comment: it denys all files. but i want some files like index.php

Comment: @jayamalladi, Create another rule similar to above for `index.php`

Answer (score 4):

You don't need `mod_rewrite` to accomplish this.  A much simpler way of doing this would be with `RedirectMatch` directive from `mod_alias`:

```
RedirectMatch 403 ^.*/include/*\.php$
```

This will automatically respond with `403 Forbidden` to a direct request for any PHP file inside `include` subdirectory, however you would still be able to `include` them from inside other php files.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use only RewriteRule without RewriteCond
For example:
`RewriteRule ^/hai\.php - [F, NS, L]`
This rule forbid access to file hai.php
For other files you can use other Rule or use mask.