# Block access to a web subdirectory with .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

My directory:

```
/root/
/root/directory1/
/root/directory2/
```

If the `.htaccess` file is located inside root,
How do I deny access to `directory1`
while allowing access to `directory2`

Could you please help by being precise? I am a total beginner, the office's pro is on vacation :) May thanks in advance!

Comment: this sounds like it should be on [sf]

Comment: [This post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13413080/block-access-to-files-and-sub-directory-with-htaccess) might help you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The *tl;dr* version is below however it is better to learn how to fish. Thus rtfm so one knows what to do instead of always asking for the answer.

I suggest reading up on how to use .htaccess to [block access](http://www.javascriptkit.com/howto/htaccess5.shtml) to a resource and how to [deny directory index](http://www.javascriptkit.com/howto/htaccess11.shtml). Also one needs to ensure that .htaccess files [cannot be directly accessable](http://www.javascriptkit.com/howto/htaccess11.shtml) with an absolute url.

Therefore your .htaccess should look something like the following:

```
#/root/.htaccess - override any .htaccess in /directory1 and /directory2

# prevent listing of directory contents
Options -Indexes

# block .htaccess from being read
<Files .htaccess>
order allow,deny
deny from all
</Files>

<Directory "/directory1">
 order deny,allow
 deny from all
</Directory>
```

Comment: Thank you guys, This is exactly what I needed! The links are very useful too. Why is it that I have to override any .htaccess located in directory1 and directory2?

Comment: @ElleVonKing generally apache follows top down processing of rules for htaccess files. Therefore if a .htaccess file in directory1 allows for say Indexing or access to the directory then having any rules overwriting those at a higher level would secure the directory anyways. Honestly any rules governiing access control should be setup in the vhost file instead and deny overrides at the docroot level with ```AllowOverride None``` in the vhost file.

Comment: @ElleVonKing the StackOverflow Question, [Apache: .htaccess file is read from the top drive directory](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24476370/apache-htaccess-file-is-read-from-the-top-drive-directory) goes into better detail about this.

Answer (score 1):

Inside `/directory1/.htaccess` place this line:

```
Deny from all
```

to block all access to `directory1`.